# How can I push an item into an es6 Map object value that is an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let exampleMap = new Map([
  ['example key', ['item in array 1', 'item in array 2']]
]);
```

I can *replace* the array with a string using `set`:

```
exampleMap.set('example key', 'new string replacing the array');
```

but how can I `push` another string into the array value so I get:

```
['example key', ['item in array 1', 'item in array 2', 'item in array 3']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map has set and get

you can't really "push" to a map, because it's a pair of key values, that are unique, what you can do is exampleMap.set('key','value') and it'll be the last element.

what you can do is exampleMap.get('example key').push('element); // first get the array then modify it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 2):

You can just use usual **push** method like this

```
exampleMap.get("example key").push('item in array 3');

console.log(exampleMap.get("example key")); // ['item in array 1', 'item in array 2', 'item in array 3']
```

Because Array are **referenced**. it means is not the values which is being pass but a reference